GEKKO: Parameter estimation on a delayed system with known delay
Here is a simple delayed system, or say a DDE

I believe the parameter k can be estimated with direct collocation method when τ is given. And the problem is how to do this with GEKKO.
Here is what I have done:
Firstly, the system is simulated with jitcdde package
from jitcdde import t, y, jitcdde
import numpy as np

# the constants in the equation
k = -0.2
tau = 0.5

# the equation
f = [    
    k*y(0, t-tau)
    ]

# initialising the integrator
DDE = jitcdde(f)

# enter initial conditions
DDE.constant_past([1.0])

# short pre-integration to take care of discontinuities
DDE.step_on_discontinuities()

# create timescale
stoptime = 10.5
numpoints = 100
times = np.arange(DDE.t, stoptime, 1/10)

# integrating
data = []
for time in times:
    data.append( DDE.integrate(time) ) # The warning is due to small sample step, no worry

Then, do the estimation
# The sample is taken every 0.1s and the delay is 0.5s
# so ydelayed should be taken 5 steps before ydata
tdata = times[5:]
ydata =  np.array(data)[5:]
ydelayed = np.array(data)[0:-5]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = tdata
x = m.CV(value=ydata); x.FSTATUS = 1 # fit to measurement
xdelayed = m.CV(value=ydelayed); x.FSTATUS = 1  # fit to measurement
k = m.FV(); k.STATUS = 1               # adjustable parameter
m.Equation(x.dt()== k * xdelayed)            # differential equation

m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 5   # collocation nodes
m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output
k = k.value[0]

which show k=-0.03253 but the true value is -0.2. How to fix the identification?

Use the m.delay() function in Gekko as shown in this Time-Delay example. It creates a discrete state-space model to simulate the delay. Because it is a mixed differential equation and discrete state-space model, the number of NODES must be 2. The result is -0.2034 instead of -0.2, likely due to the discretization error with NODES=2.
from gekko import GEKKO
# The sample is taken every 0.1s and the delay is 0.5s
# so ydelayed should be taken 5 steps before ydata
tdata = times[5:]
ydata =  np.array(data)[5:]
ydelayed = np.array(data)[0:-5]

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = tdata
xdata = m.Param(ydata)
x = m.Var(value=ydata)
xdelayed = m.Var(value=ydelayed)
m.delay(x,xdelayed,5)

m.Minimize((x-xdata)**2)

k = m.FV(); k.STATUS = 1               # adjustable parameter
m.Equation(x.dt()== k * xdelayed)            # differential equation

m.options.IMODE = 5   # dynamic estimation
m.options.NODES = 2   # collocation nodes

for i in range(5):
  xdata.value = ydata
  m.solve(disp=False)   # display solver output
k = k.value[0]
print(k)

There is also an initialization issue because the delay states are unknown from [0:4] because there is no past information on the states. The problem is solved repeatedly with m.options.TIME_SHIFT=1 (default) to simulate the receding horizon.

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.figure(figsize=(6,3))
plt.plot(m.time,x.value,'ro',label='Meas')
plt.plot(m.time,xdata,'b--',label='Pred')
plt.legend(); plt.grid()
plt.show()

It is also possible to estimate the time-delay as shown with exogenous inputs as shown with this self-contained example of another first-order linear system.

import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from gekko import GEKKO
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Import CSV data file
# Column 1 = time (t)
# Column 2 = input (u)
# Column 3 = output (yp)
url = 'http://apmonitor.com/pdc/uploads/Main/data_fopdt.txt'
data = pd.read_csv(url)
t = data['time'].values - data['time'].values[0]
u = data['u'].values
y = data['y'].values

m = GEKKO(remote=False)
m.time = t; time = m.Var(0); m.Equation(time.dt()==1)

K = m.FV(2,lb=0,ub=10);      K.STATUS=1
tau = m.FV(3,lb=1,ub=200);  tau.STATUS=1
theta_ub = 30 # upper bound to dead-time
theta = m.FV(0,lb=0,ub=theta_ub); theta.STATUS=1

# add extrapolation points
td = np.concatenate((np.linspace(-theta_ub,min(t)-1e-5,5),t))
ud = np.concatenate((u[0]*np.ones(5),u))
# create cubic spline with t versus u
uc = m.Var(u); tc = m.Var(t); m.Equation(tc==time-theta)
m.cspline(tc,uc,td,ud,bound_x=False)

ym = m.Param(y); yp = m.Var(y)
m.Equation(tau*yp.dt()+(yp-y[0])==K*(uc-u[0]))

m.Minimize((yp-ym)**2)

m.options.IMODE=5
m.solve()

print('Kp: ', K.value[0])
print('taup: ',  tau.value[0])
print('thetap: ', theta.value[0])

# plot results
plt.figure()
plt.subplot(2,1,1)
plt.plot(t,y,'k.-',lw=2,label='Process Data')
plt.plot(t,yp.value,'r--',lw=2,label='Optimized FOPDT')
plt.ylabel('Output')
plt.legend()
plt.subplot(2,1,2)
plt.plot(t,u,'b.-',lw=2,label='u')
plt.legend()
plt.ylabel('Input')
plt.show()


I am a bit confused by "initialization issue on no past information": the problem is not a real-time one, the delayed state can be acquired by data[i-5] while the current state is data[i]. Another question is how TIME_SHIFT=1 shifts data and why xdata.value = ydata is called in iteration?

Gekko uses a moving window of data that shifts (default: TIME_SHIFT=1) every time m.solve() is called. When .MEAS is assigned, it inserts the data point at the end of the data array and shifts (rolls) all prior points down by one index. The purple region of the window shows a Moving Horizon Estimation: https://apmonitor.com/do/uploads/Main/tclab_mhe_mpc.mp4  The same thing happens to the prior states that shift left to give a new initial condition and initial guess for the states that are solved with the DAE equations. Try setting range(5) to something lower to see the effect.
